# Django - How to redirect the user after the first login only

Tags: django

I would like to redirect the user to a custom 'welcome' page when they first log into the website. But anytime they log in after that they just get redirected to the home page '/' like normal.

I am thinking I can use the "last login" field that the user has, because when they have not logged in yet it is marked as 'None' I think?

I am thinking something like:

```
if User.last_login == None:
        return redirect('welcome_page.html')
    else:
        return render(request, '/')
```

But I dont think it will be that simple, and I am not even sure what areas I should be looking in / changing to add that code in. I was hoping someone would have some advice as my research has come up empty so far and I haven't been able to get anything to work.

Comment: That attribute might be set already somewhere in auth middleware. I would not rely on that. If you need this funtionaluty, IMO it is better to define custom attribute, like `first_login` with `True` as default value. Now before you redirect to the first-login page, you set this attribute to `False` and save the user model.

Comment: Just like what @rubick said, you might want to extend your ```User``` model and add another field which you will check if it's ```True``` or ```False```.

Comment: @rubick Thank you, I will try to go about it this way instead that makes sense. I'm just curious, the redirect I will need to edit, will that be in 'my_app/views.py'. Basically put the if statement for the custom flag in there and then if it's true direct them to the custom page then else direct them to 'index.html' like normal?